# How to convert SQL (count, order by) to LINQ (count, order by)?

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I have a query here and its working in SQL, but I am using LINQ and I don't know how to convert it. Can anyone help me?

This is my query:

```
select o.name, count(o.officeID) 
from SysTransaction t 
left join SysOffice o on t.officeID = o.officeID 
group by o.officeID
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count

Comment: no its not. it didn't use left join and I already tried it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin
or
https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: it don't have count.

Comment: please help me, this problem damages me for last 2 days.

Comment: Possible duplicate. [stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count)

Comment: Are you shure that want to group by o.officeID not t.officeID. o.officeID may be null in case of left join, also count(o.name) tells that more probably to group by t.officeID, because it will calculate only non null values from right side of join.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and the problem you've run into, rather than just saying it didn't work.

Comment: this is the LINQ:
_from trans in db.SysTransactions
                .Where(x => x.datestart >= '2016-01-04' && x.dateend <= '2016-01-08' && (x.SysOffice.code + " - (" + x.SysOffice.name + ")").Contains("MIS"))
              join office in db.SysOffices
                on trans.officeID equals office.officeID
                into transoff
              select new
              {
                trans.officeID,
                trans.SysOffice.name,
                trans.SysOffice.code,
                count = transoff.Count()
           };_
this is the result:
http://postimg.org/image/upimxt4fp/

Comment: To clarify, you want a count of transactions by office, but not all transactions have an office ?

Comment: A good question would have included the SQL that supposeldy is working, your attempts at LINQ, a desription how it fails and a statement what you want to achieve.

Comment: **@Murph:** I want to count how many times an office had a transaction in my list. ex: Office1 (count 2). this image will help you to visualized.postimg.org/image/upimxt4fp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
from t in sysTransaction
join o in sysOffice on t.OfficeId equals o.OfficeId into joined
from one in joined
group one by one.OfficeId into grouped
select new
{
    officeId = grouped.Key,
    count = grouped.Count()
};
```